# Bookmark panel in Chrome/Chromium like in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, chromium

I really would like to use Chrome/Chromium, but what I am missing hardly is a bookmark panel, which is shown all the time, like in Firefox and in most other browsers. By "bookmark panel" I mean the tree that lists all bookmarks and that is displayed on the left side (what you get when you press CTRL + B in Firefox, Firefox calls it a "Sidebar").

I couldn't find a extension for that. Does some has an idea?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/niutech/chrome-devtools-sidebar

Comment: You have to use  `Bookmark Manager extension for Chrome` https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-manager/gmlllbghnfkpflemihljekbapjopfjik?hl=en

Answer (score 5):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> for the [Chrome 5](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95745) (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> for Chrome 6).

And bookmark sidebar probably [would not be added](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45365):

> [I don't think](http://chromespot.com/forum/google-chrome-tips-and-tricks/3504-bookmarks-sidebar.html) Google would consider that; part of Chrome's appeal is the
>   minimalistic interface. Many users of other browsers have complained as to
>   how bulky sidebars can be, so I doubt Google will add them.

But anyway, you could check a [non-ideal way](http://chromespot.com/forum/12388-post7.html) to make something sidebar-like.

Comment: That just opens the 'Bookmark Manager', but that is not a panel that is visible all the time.

Comment: In my Chrome 6 the panel **is** shown in all tabs, like in Firefox. Anyway, you could try clicking on the rightmost button in the toolbar (with a 'configure' icon) and select the "Always Show Bookmarks Bar" option.

Comment: Just discovered that it is [Ctrl+B in Windows](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95745)

Comment: Sorry, I guess my question was too vague. I actually mean the "Bookmark Sidebar" like in Firefox.

And under Linux it is also Ctrl-B (at least for Chromium 5).

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: the minimalistic interface is most terrible thing for me.  It is much easier to close bulky sidebars than to find what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the sidebar- if you want "firefox like" bookmark thing use the "live bookmarks" extension in chrome. i used to love firefox but its so buggy now its nearly useless...

Xmarks is also a very cool extension

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the exact same thing then came across **[CoolNovo](http://coolnovo.com/)** which is based on Chrome and has a sidebar.

I just installed it, set up syncing with my Google account and it's syncing all my extensions and bookmarks right now. It basically seems the same as Chrome on first look which is great. I'm using the portable version at the moment to try it out. Check the screenshot for how the sidebar looks with Bookmarks.

It doesn't fix the problem in Chrome, but it's a good alternative so far.

[image]

([Click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl2YB.jpg))

Comment: Just an update, CoolNovo is dead and most likely CooWon would be best alternative. http://coowon.com/

Answer (score 0):

- Open bookmark manager
- (Use [Open-as-Popup](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ncppfjladdkdaemaghochfikpmghbcpc) or similar extension if you want, to hide all toolbars and tabbar)
- Tile windows or manually resize them to be side-by-side
- Or you can alternatively make bookmark window on-top/transparent/easily brought up (with win+#/taskbar icon click in Win7 or something similar to gain focus of it)

If you want just some means to manage "sessions" of pages that should be easily accessible but not in the memory, you can use one of extensions that allow you to manage tabs in sidebar fashion (be sure to read detailed extension description)

- [Tabs Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl)
- [Sideways Tree Style Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/biiammgklaefagjclmnlialkmaemifgo)
- [Tab-Sidebar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/egmcoemabahnkbkfgdifiafkhebcfpfo) -not sure if this one has tab unloading

Answer (score 0):

Take look on [TabsOutliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl?hl=en).

Not exactly a sidebar but it is solve this exact problem and actually solve it much better than a some sidebar.

In additional to give you overview of all your windows and tabs it is allow save them as links, "in place" (so, without losing the context)

See a screenshot (gray window and tab is saved):
[image]